# Adding X-WR-CALNAME to DDay.iCal.iCalendar.Calendar

Tags: icalendar, dday

I'm using the excellent [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/pages/projects/dday.ical/) to read iCal files from Google Calendar.

Each iCal file has a non-standard property of X-WR-CALNAME.

How do I add this to the DDay.iCal.iCalendar.Calendar object?

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it... don't know if it's the right way, but it works for me.

```
var iCal = new iCalendar();
iCal.Method = CalendarMethods.Publish;
iCal.AddLocalTimeZone();
iCal.AddProperty("X-WR-CALNAME", "Calendar Name");
```